# Plot contents from csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a `csv` file that contains three columns. One for date, other for time on that date and third for price. How can I plot the `csv` file as the price on y axis and date and time on x axis? Every date contains the same time values from 10:00-19:00. Like for example on 21st Feb 10:00 value is 100, at 10:01 value is 102..., 19:00 value is 106. On Feb 22 at 10:00 value is 107. Same goes for every day but prices change.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.genfromtxt('a.csv',delimiter=',', dtype = float)

b = [row[1] for row in data]
c = [row[2] for row in data]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg = 'w')
ax.plot(b,c,'r',lw=1.3)
plt.ylabel('Price value of stock')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

But with this code I could not plot the time in accordance to the date.It just plots the price vs time regardless of date which is in column 0.

csv looks like this:

```
14062004    1000    15.29
14062004    1001    15.16
14062004    1002    15.14
14062004    1003    15.22
14062004    1004    15.18
```

Comment: please post the code that you tried ..

Comment: Do you want us to right a complete program for you? Or do you have anything you've already worked on?

Comment: Added the code.yes a little help would do.

Comment: This one looks nice, why don't you try to duplicate their methods?  http://pythonio.com/blog/2013/01/07/python-time-series-showing-stock-price-trading-volume/   --- This was the first hit on a google search for "plot stock prices python".

Answer (score 0):

First off use the csv.reader module to the file into Python.
Check out an example here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Now, you can use datetime.datetime.strptime to cast the date and time into a "datetime.datetime" object. The price you can store, as a Float or an Integer.

Now, make a 'list' of all Price values in the order of the times at which they existed.
Next up, make a 'list' of time elapsed from the starting time, for all the date time objects you have.
(The datetime objects are quite magical in that you can actually subtract them. You get a datetime.timedelta object using attributes of which you can obtain the time difference in days,minutes,etc)

You can then do a common X-Y axis plot, using matplotlib or any tool you prefer.
If you wish to do plot outside Python (in Excel, MATLAB, etc). You can  write the lists back to a CSV file using csv.writer. (google up for example code)

This would be a starter. Later on, you may want to nullify the effect of the large change in time between 19:00 on one day to 10:00 on the next day, to make the plot more meaningful maybe.